# Solving differential equation without IVP or fundamental solution : $\displaystyle \phi ^{"} -x \phi ^{'} + x^2 \phi = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While studying about Differential Equations I randomly came up with  the equation mentioned below.

$\displaystyle \phi ^{"} -x \phi ^{'} + x^2 \phi = 0  $ is actually the equation I got while solving for the RICCATI EQUATION :

$$\displaystyle y' = x^2 + xy + y^2 $$

When we use the substitution $\displaystyle y = \frac {- \phi ^{'} }{\phi} ,$ one can get the above mentioned Second Order homogeneous differential equation.

---

**My attempt :**

I thought to think of a general solution to $ \ \displaystyle \phi ^{"} -x \phi ^{'} + x^2 \phi = 0  $

So I used the same old ordinary technique, THE CHARACTERISTIC EQUATION ( i.e substituting $ \ \displaystyle \phi = e^{rx}) $

We will a quadratic equation : $ \ \displaystyle r^2 - rx + x^2 = 0 ; \text {giving} \ r= -x\omega , -x \omega ^2 .$

Then choosing any one of them, and using ABEL's theorem, I found another LINEARLY INDEPENDENT SOLUTION, using **Wronskian** (by definition). (But I doubt on their Linear Independent nature)

But it was too complicated. Let me show you.

Assuming $ \ \displaystyle r = -x \omega ^2 $, one will get :

$$ \displaystyle \phi = c_1 e^{x^2/2}. e^{\iota \sqrt {3}x^2/2}  - \frac {c_2 }{x^3 + x + \iota 2\sqrt {3} \ x} \left ( e^{-x^4/4}. e^{\iota \sqrt {3} x^2 /2} \right ) $$

Now solving for $y$ would be hard.

But when I found solution for the Riccati equation on wolfram, it showed : $ \ \displaystyle y = \frac {1}{c - x} - \frac {x}{2}  .$

---

I would like to know that the function $\phi$ which I found is general or not. And if there is a method to find the solution to second order differential equation with variable coefficients (homogeneous or non-homogeneous) without the knowledge of any prior common function that solves the equation.

And please tell a good method to solve for the Riccati equation mentioned above.

---

Edit the tags if required, i do not know what to add more.

---

**EDITS:** In relation to the comment by *Winther* , when I checked for the solution provided by wolfram... it did not satisfy the equation. Please share a method to solve it.

---

**THANK YOU.**

Comment: "But when I found solution for the Riccati equation on wolfram" Did you try to check manually that $y = 1/(c-x) - x/2$ actually solves the equation? Try to plug in and see. Also your method with characteristic polynomial is flawed (it only applies to equations with constant coefficients)

Comment: Thanks Winther, for pointing out the flaw. And checking for the solution by wolfram.

Comment: I find that the function do not satisfy the equation.

Comment: This does not seem to have a closed-form solution in elementary functions.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, please clarify that why is it the case here.

Comment: I searched for it... and found about LIOUVILLIAN EXTENSION. I guess I need to study more. Ok, is so there a method to find particular or fundamental solution of second order differential equation ?

Comment: You can find a solution in the form of an infinite power-series ( [Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) ). The kind of power-series you will find pops up here and there and are given a particular name (Hermite functions, hypergeometrical series, etc.). So you can find a solution in terms of these non-elementay functions, but that I think is as good as you are going to get.

Comment: @Winther , Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining $u(x)=e^{-x^2/4}\phi(x)$, we can rewrite the differential equation
$$
\phi''-x\phi'+x^2\phi=0 \tag{1}
$$
as
$$
u''+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}x^2\right)u=0. \tag{2}
$$
The change of variable $x=\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{1/4}z$ transforms ($2$) into Weber's differential equation$^{(a)}$
$$
u''(z)+\left(\nu+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}z^2\right)u(z)=0 \tag{3}
$$
with the parameter $\nu=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}$. The general solution to ($3$) is
$$
u(z)=c_1D_{\nu}(z)+c_2D_{-\nu-1}(iz), \tag{4}
$$
where $D_{\nu}(z)$ is the so-called parabolic cylinder function. Therefore, the general solution to $(1)$ is
$$
\phi(x)=e^{x^2/4}\left[c_1D_{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}}\left((-3)^{1/4}x\right)+
c_2D_{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}}\left(i(-3)^{1/4}x\right) \right]. \tag{5}
$$

---

$^{(a)}$Weisstein, Eric W. "Parabolic Cylinder Function." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. But currently it is beyond my understanding... I will definitely look into the solution in near future. Currently  I do not know the Hypergeometric functions and  etc.. so i will do some research about them and return to your solution.